# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; breaks scrolling iFrame on the iPad

Tags: css, ipad, iframe, scroll

From everything I have been able to find I need to include -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; and overflow:auto in the css for the iFrames enclosing div.

What I have found, however, is that if I do not include -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;, the iFrame will scroll with 2 fingers. If, however, I include it scrolling no longer works.

Here is an example of my html with style in line. I am actually using a CSS file but have tried it this way too...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="treeMenu" ></div>
    <div class="viewer" style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch">
        <iframe class='ifrm' scrolling='yes'></iframe>
    </div>      
</div>
```

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620736/webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch-breaks-on-ipad-when-toggeling-visibility-on-ipa) I thought this might be due to the fact that I was removing and adding the iFrame to the div dynamically. So I changed it be a static element and changed the iFrame's src dynamically. This did not fix the problem.

I am resizing the div based on user interactions before the user taps a link to fill the iFrame. Could this be the problem?

Leaving the webkit call off and scrolling with 2 fingers is fine, except that the scrolling is anything but smooth. In fact it may border on unusable for some users. I was hoping that setting up scrolling "properly" for the iPad would improve the scrolling performance.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` doesn't work properly if there is an `<iframe>` anywhere on the page, even if it is not the `<iframe>` you are trying to scroll. It doesn't matter how it is created or displayed.